# How to set the min_frequency while using tf.keras.preprocessing.text.tokenizer and ignore the words which are less then min_frequency?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

Is there any way to set the 'min_frequency' in tf.keras.preprocessing.text.tokenizer, just like the 'min_frequency' in tf.contrib.learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor?

Answer (score 0):

The `num_words` actually helps in doing the same thing, here `num_words` will take the top `num_words` words with the highest frequency.

So, the functionality you got from `min_frequency` in `tf.contrib.learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor` you can get the same but not in the same way though.